# XMLWorker: CSS does not work only if it is selected the "class" attribute of a TAG

Tags: css, itext

I use a very simple CSS in XMLWorker to render HTML to PDFs. Here is the CSS:

```
body { font-family: "Times New Roman;" } 

p.testoJustify { 
text-align:justify; 
text-justify:inter-word; 
}
```

The problem is on the ".testoJustify" selector. When I use this selector, the resulting PDF doesn't have the text justified, while without the selector, so only with p {... }, it works fine!

The java code is the following:

```
FontFactory.registerDirectories(); 

XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider(); 
CssAppliers cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider); 
HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers); 
htmlContext.setTagFactory(Tags.getHtmlTagProcessorFactory()); 

CSSResolver cssResolver =XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().getDefaultCssResolver(true); 
cssResolver.addCss(Context.pdfCss, true); 
Pipeline<?> pipeline = new CssResolverPipeline(cssResolver, 
                                                new HtmlPipeline(htmlContext, 
                                                  new PdfWriterPipeline(pdfDocument, pdfWriter)));
```

This is the link to JSFiddle showing that CSS is corrected applied on HTML page, but not XMLWorker:

http://jsfiddle.net/6vrMP/

Comment: Only that particular class, or do other classes have the same problem?

Comment: other classes too. There is another class called 'testoCenter' where the problem is the same.

Comment: No comments? Only me has that problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have been digging in the source code of the XmlWorker and complex selectors are not supported

You have technically two approaches:

- Inline all the style, using for example CSSBox library as in the example https://github.com/radkovo/CSSBox/blob/master/src/main/java/org/fit/cssbox/demo/ComputeStyles.java
- Write your css using simple selectors (only classes, for example) at the cost of having to write

  ```
   <table>
     <tr>
        <td class="a">
        <td class="a">
     </tr>
   </table>
  ```

instead of

```
     <table class="a">
       <tr>
          <td>
          <td>
       </tr>
     </table>
```

because you can't write

```
.a td { smth }
```

If your html is not too big, I would go for the second approach.